# How to POST additional parameters to editurl?

Tags: perl, jqgrid, catalyst

I've spent several hours looking at examples and docs trying to figure out how to POST additional parameters to `editurl`, and have yet to figure this out. I'm using Perl Catalyst.

Though I don't have it all coded in the controller, I am getting what I need POSTed to add and edit, but not to delete records. I need `inv_id` to be POSTed to the server for my controller to delete a record.

Controller/Root.pm:

```perl
package MyFirstGrid::Controller::Root;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

BEGIN {extends 'Catalyst::Controller'}
with 'Catalyst::TraitFor::Controller::jQuery::jqGrid';

__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => '');

sub index :Path :Args(0) {
  my ($self, $c) = @_;

  $c->detach($c->view("TT"));
}

sub getdata :Local {
  my ($self, $c) = @_;

  my $inv_rs = $c->model('DB::Inventory')->search({});
  $inv_rs = $self->jqgrid_page($c, $inv_rs);
  my @row_data;
  while (my $inv = $inv_rs->next) {
    my $single_row = {
      cell => [
        $inv->inv_id,
        $inv->client_id,
        $inv->amount,
        $inv->tax,
        $inv->total,
        $inv->note,
      ],
    };
    push @row_data, $single_row;
  }
  $c->stash->{json_data}{rows} = \@row_data;
  $c->detach($c->view("JSON")); 
}

sub postrow :Local {
  my ($self, $c) = @_;

  my $data = $c->req->params;
  my $inv_rs = $c->model('DB::Inventory')->search({inv_id => $data->{inv_id}});
  $inv_rs->update({
    client_id => $data->{client_id},
    amount => $data->{amount},
    tax => $data->{tax}, 
    total => $data->{total}, 
    note => $data->{note}, 
  });
  $c->res->status(204); 
}

sub default :Path {
  my ($self, $c) = @_;

  $c->response->body('Page not found');
  $c->response->status(404);
}

sub end : ActionClass('RenderView') {}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

index.tt:

```xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="[% c.uri_for('/static/css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css') %]" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="[% c.uri_for('/static/css/ui.jqgrid.css') %]" />

<style type="text/css">
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 75%;
}
</style>

<script src="[% c.uri_for('/static/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js') %]" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="[% c.uri_for('/static/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js') %]" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="[% c.uri_for('/static/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js') %]" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
  $("#list").jqGrid({
    url: "[% c.uri_for("getdata") %]",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['Inv No', 'Client ID', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel :[ 
      //{name:'inv_id', index:'inv_id', editable:true, hidden:true, editrules:{edithidden:false}, hidedlg:true}, 
      {name:'inv_id', index:'inv_id', editable:true, hidden:true}, 
      {name:'client_id', index:'client_id', width:55, editable:true, editoptions:{size:10}},
      {name:'amount', index:'amount', width:80, align:'right', editable:true, editoptions:{size:10}}, 
      {name:'tax', index:'tax', width:80, align:'right', editable:true, editoptions:{size:10}}, 
      {name:'total', index:'total', width:80, align:'right', editable:true, editoptions:{size:10}}, 
      {name:'note', index:'note', width:150, sortable:false, editable: true, edittype:"textarea", editoptions:{rows:"2",cols:"20"}} 
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    sortname: 'inv_id',
    sortorder: 'desc',
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'My First Grid: Navigator',
    editurl: "[% c.uri_for("postrow") %]",
    height: 240
  }); 

  jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
    {}, //options
    {height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // edit options
    {height:280,reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // add options
    {reloadAfterSubmit:false}, // del options 
    {} // search options
  ); 

}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="list"><tr><td/></tr></table> 
<div id="pager"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just watched your ["Notes from a Newbie"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkbfJQ8NfKA "Notes from a Newbie") talk from YAPC::NA on YouTube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the origin of the problem which you have is in *filling* of the grid. During filling of the grid all grid's rows (`<tr>` elements) get the `id` attribute. During editing and deleting of the rows the value of `id` attribute of the corresponding row will be send always to the server. It's important to know that the values of `id` attributes have to be unique on the page. If the values of `inv_id` are unique, that you can use this values directly as the `id`. To inform jqGrid about the choice you can either add `jsonReader: {id: "inv_id"}` as additional grid parameter or just to add `key: true` property to the definition of the `inv_id` column.

I don't use Perl Catalyst myself, but the part where you fill the grid data (see `my $single_row = { cell => [...]}`) seems to me should contain `id` property additionally to `cell` property (something like `$single_row = {cell => [...], id => $inv->inv_id}`). If the `inv_id` is unique it would be better enough to add `key: true` to the definition of the `inv_id` column and your problem will be already solved.

If you already use another value of `id` and you really need to have both values: the `id` and `inv_id` then you can use for example [onclickSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events2) callback of delete options. The

```js
onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
    return {inv_id: $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "inv_id")};
}
```

I mean to use the following

```js
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {}, //options
    {height: 280, reloadAfterSubmit: false}, // edit options
    {height: 280, reloadAfterSubmit: false}, // add options
    { // del options
        reloadAfterSubmit: false,
        onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
            return {inv_id: $(this).jqGrid("getCell", rowid, "inv_id")};
        }
    }
);
```

As the result the data posted to the server during Delete operation will be extended with additional parameter `inv_id`.

Comment: Adding the key:true property to the inv_id definition gives me exactly what I need, as simple as that. Oleg, you be the man!

Comment: I created a tutorial from this question: http://blogs.perl.org/users/j0e/2012/09/using-jqgrid-with-catalyst-tutorial-with-examples-for-newbies.html